# Get page feeds from facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook api for getting feeds from facebook page.
Here is the code I am using:

```
session_start(); 
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once ('Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once ('Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once ( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app_id', 'app_secret');
$session = new FacebookSession('access_token');
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

// To validate the session:
try {
  $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I have added app_id, app_secret,page-id and access_token in the code. But I am getting the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {page-id}
```

But if I open https://graph.facebook.com/page-id?access_token=my_access_token, I get the required data.
I am doing all the stuff on localhost. Can some one help me finding the error?

Comment: So, do I understand this correctly, in the actual code you replaced {page_id} with a real page's object id?

Comment: Yes.I have added the actual page id

Comment: Is the problem due to localhost? I am trying the script on localhost.